# how to fit image inside TD of HTML table

Tags: html, css

I am displaying an image inside TD using:

But image seems to be taking larger width than the width defined for the TD.

Please provide me some solution.

Comment: Post your HTML/CSS so we can see what you tried.  Create a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 14):

CSS solution

```
td img {
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

Comment: Bearing in mind that this will apply to *all* images inside a table's td.  To the OP, if you want only a specific img then your selector would need to be more specific than this.  Nice CSS solution @aCodeSmith

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

If you want ALL `<td>`'s to have images:

HTML:

```
<table class="imagetable">

<tr>

<td>Hey wat up</td>

</tr>

</table>
```

CSS:

```
.tableimage td {
background-image:url('http://example.com/image.jpg');
background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

If you just want ONE `<td>` to have an image

HTML:

```
<td class="image">Hey wat up</td>
```

CSS:

```
.image {
background-image:url('http://example.com/image.jpg');
background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: this solution will work only if the `<td>` has contents within, otherwise the `<td>` won't be displayed.

Comment: @Raptor true, so i guess you could add some padding or fixed width to the `<td>`'s